# How does Photofunia render and mask images on predefined templates?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

How does [Photofunia](https://photofunia.com/) mask images on predefined templates?

Is it possible to do that with PHP? Do I need special technology? Thank you for your help and guidance.

> ### the original image:
>
> [image]

> ### the rendered image by photofunia:
>
> [image]

Comment: You can do that with PHP Imagick which uses ImageMagick. Both are typically pre-installed on Linux, but can be installed on Windows and Mac. You can also use PHP exec() to run ImageMagick commands without Imagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `imagemagick`.

The current release is **ImageMagick** `7.0.11-12`. It runs on `Linux`, `Windows`, `Mac Os X`, `iOS`, `Android` OS, and others.

please read this documentation:
[imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/) , [example](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/), [other doc](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php), [php sample](https://github.com/darrynten/pslayers)

enjoy it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Imagik php library for masking images and use pslayers library to create a softlight mode similar to Photoshop.
https://github.com/darrynten/pslayers

Comment: Is there any library for nodeJS/javascript?